# 06/14/2022 09:37:48" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am working on some PowerShell script that checks the difference in time between passwords of the same account in two domains. However, I am getting the following error: 13:39:58  06/09/2022 15:49:37 06/09/2022 15:51:01 06/14/2022 09:37:48" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I have no idea how to solve this.

The code:

```
    $UPN = "*contoso.com"

$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like '$UPN'"

Foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    $Domain1 = (Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like '$UPN'" -Properties passwordlastset | Select passwordlastset).passwordlastset
    $Domain2 = (Get-ADUser -Server "DOMAIN.TWO.COM" -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like '$UPN'" -Properties passwordlastset | Select passwordlastset).passwordlastset
    $Difference = NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $Domain2 –End $Domain1
    
    if($Domain1 -ne $null -and $Domain2 -ne $null)
    {
        if(($Difference.Minutes)*-1 -gt 5)
        {
            Write-Host "Password is not in sync"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `$Domain1` and/or `$Domain2` contain more than one DateTime because your AD query resolves to more than one user.  If this is the case, you'll need to loop through them and process them individually.

Answer (score 0):

That error is because you're dealing with **arrays** of dates.
Although your code iterates the users you got from the first `Get-ADUser` call one by one, inside that loop you repeat that call `Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like '$UPN'"`) so there again you get an **array** of users..

Try something like

```
# get an array of user objects
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like '*contoso.com'" -Properties PasswordLastSet
# iterate one-by-one
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    if ($User.PasswordLastSet) {
        # try and get the same user from the second domain
        $Domain2 = Get-ADUser -Server "DOMAIN.TWO.COM" -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($User.UserPrincipalName)'" -Properties PasswordLastSet
        if ($Domain2 -and $null -ne $Domain2.PassPasswordLastSet) {
            # we found the user in the second domain
            $Difference = New-TimeSpan -Start $Domain2.PasswordLastSet -End $User.PasswordLastSet
            if ([math]::Abs($Difference.Minutes) -gt 5) {
                Write-Host "Password is not in sync for user '$($User.Name)'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>P.S. the dashes you used on the `-Start` and `-End` parameters for the New-TimeSpan cmdlet were not 'normal' hyphens, but EN-Dashes instead..</sup>

Comment: Hi Theo,
Thanks for your reply! However, receiving the following error with your script: New-TimeSpan : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection' to the type 'System.DateTime' required by parameter 'Start'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: @Ralph I edited the `$Difference=` line a few minutes ago. Please try the latest revision

Comment: Hi Theo. I used the updated version, but still same error. Thanks for your help! Really appreciated.

Comment: @Ralph I guess you didn't copy correctly then.. The `New-TimeSpan` in my code uses DateTime objects (`$Domain2.PassPasswordLastSet` and `$User.PasswordLastSet`) which is the correct way. Did you forget any of the `-Properties PasswordLastSet` on the Get-ADUser cmdlets? perhaps?

Comment: Thanks! It's working by changing PassPasswordLastSet to PasswordLastSet.

Comment: @Ralph Aaargh.. so it was me who did a copy/paste error. Didn't see that, sorry.

Comment: No worries @Theo. You helped me really great. Appreciated your support :)